# Is there a workaround for the bug that the username is not saved in openconnect VPN connection dialog

Tags: networking, gnome, vpn, openvpn, openconnect

When you connect a VPN with OpenConnect, I can click on "save passwords" but only the password is filled in automatically when I open the connection dialogue the next time. **The "Username" field is empty** and needs to be filled in every time! There are **bug reports** on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1838838) and [Gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2105), please **help** if you can, its priority is only low!?!
Is there a workaround till the bug is fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following workaround worked for me (Source: [Gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2105#note_833969)).
In a **terminal** (e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
nmcli con mod VPNNAME vpn.secrets 'form:main:username=USERNAME','save_passwords=yes'
```

Replace VPNNAME with the name you gave to the VPN connection and USERNAME with the username for this specific VPN connection.

Update Dec 2020: [Sebastian Keller figured out the problem](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2105#note_981097) and made a [commit](https://gitlab.gnome.org/skeller/gnome-shell/-/commit/eb95f6a0fabc0a7ec04d747925d303ce2e411368) to this problem, hopefully it will soon reach the different distros.

Update 2022: This is solved in Ubuntu 22.04 but still a problem in Ubuntu 20.04